# Why doesn't ulimit -n work when called inside a script?

Tags: linux, shell-script, ulimit

This is very odd. I'm trying to set the `ulimit` to `60000` via my `startup.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

ulimit -n 60000
echo "Hello! File Descriptor set"
```

I can execute this with `./startup.sh` (755 file permissions) and the echo line is printed, and no errors are shown. However, when I do `ulimit -n` it still shows `1024`, what's going on?

What I also find fascinating is I can type `ulimit -n 60000` in the terminal, and then do `ulimit -n` and it works perfectly.  Why can't I set the file descriptor limit through a script?

Debian 8, 64-bit. OpenVZ Container

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ulimits are *per-process*, not per-user nor per-system.

The `ulimit` command is built into the shell, so it remains within the same process; however, the adjusted limit only affects *that* process, as well as everything you run from it (child processes inherit the same limits).

However, `./startup.sh` runs as a *separate* process – therefore it successfully adjusts *its own* limits but this does not magically propagate upwards to its parent.

(This is the same situation as with `cd` or `export – even though you can use those in a script, they all change parameters of the script's own process, not of the whole system, and will be forgotten once the script's process exits.)

Note: There *is* another command, `prlimit`, which lets you adjust resource limits of another process (specified by PID). A script could change the file limit of its parent process like this:

```
prlimit --pid=$PPID --nofile=4096
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the detailed explanation. Kept thinking it was a global setting or something.

Comment: @John Normally the closest thing to a global setting would be `/proc/sys/fs/file-max`. Since you're inside a container, OpenVZ may also be applying various limits seen in `/proc/user_beancounters`.